# postgresql full-text index scan performance fluctuates

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I encountered a problem when using postgresql full-text index scan
We have a table called "medical_record", contains about 7 million pieces of data, create the following index (using pg_bigm extension)

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_bigm;
CREATE INDEX "medical_record_content_bigm_gin_index" ON "medical_record" USING gin (content "public"."gin_bigm_ops");
```

And execute the following two queries (match Chinese)

```
explain analyse 
SELECT id
FROM medical_record
WHERE (medical_record.content LIKE '%手术历史%');

explain analyse 
SELECT id
FROM medical_record
WHERE (medical_record.content LIKE '%住院历史%');
```

But we got an unexpected execution plan: big difference in execution time...

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on medical_record  (cost=22.97..791.85 rows=693 width=4) (actual time=160.255..1709.549 rows=204828 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (content ~~ '%手术历史%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4147
  Heap Blocks: exact=194609
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on medical_record_content_bigm_gin_index  (cost=0.00..22.79 rows=693 width=0) (actual time=124.384..124.384 rows=208975 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (content ~~ '%手术历史%'::text)
Planning Time: 4.335 ms
Execution Time: 1717.109 ms

Bitmap Heap Scan on medical_record  (cost=23.06..805.30 rows=705 width=4) (actual time=591.439..35790.921 rows=620916 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (content ~~ '%住院历史%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 567636
  Heap Blocks: exact=611774
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on medical_record_content_bigm_gin_index  (cost=0.00..22.89 rows=705 width=0) (actual time=426.960..426.961 rows=1188552 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (content ~~ '%住院历史%'::text)
Planning Time: 4.974 ms
Execution Time: 35827.395 ms
```

As we can see, there is a big difference in the number of tuples that perform "recheck". is it related to the actual storage location and degree of dispersion of the data? we guess that this problem affects performance.
Please kindly give us some suggestions and clues, thanks.

Comment: It seems like every individual bigram if your latter text is popular in your documents, just not put together in that particular order.  Does that seem plausible?  Have you tried a pg_trgm instead?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, most of the scenes are Chinese input, we only reproduced this issue in the production environment, so we will look for opportunities to try to test pg_trgm.